# Lie group homomorphism induces Lie algebra homomorphism, proof with Ad and ad

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I want to show that if $\phi:G\to H$  is a Lie group homomorphism, then $d\phi:\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{h}$  is a Lie algebra homomorphism. The proof given in the classroom is the following: let $x \in G$. Since $\phi$ is a Lie group homomorphism, we have that
$$\phi(xyx^{-1}) = \phi(x) \phi(y) \phi(x)^{-1} \tag{$1$}$$
for all $y \in G$. Differentiating $(\ast)$ with respect to $y$ at $y = 1$ in the direction of $Y \in \mathfrak{g}$ gives us
$$d\phi(\mathrm{Ad}(x) Y) = \mathrm{Ad}(\phi(x)) d\phi(Y). \tag{$2$}$$
Differentiating $(2)$ with respect to $x$ at $x = 1$ in the direction of $X \in \mathfrak{g}$, we obtain
$$d\phi(\mathrm{ad}(X) Y) = \mathrm{ad}(d\phi(X)) d\phi(Y) \tag{3}$$
and so:
$$d\phi([X, Y]_{\mathfrak{g}}) = [d\phi(X), d\phi(Y)]_{\mathfrak{h}}. \tag{4}$$

$(1)\implies(2)$, because, if $C_z:G\to G$ is $C_z(g)=zgz^{-1}$, (i use same notation for $C_z:H\to H$ if $z\in H$), (1) is: $\phi \circ C_x=C_\phi(x)\circ\phi$, differentiating wrt $e\in G$, $e=1_G$, and evaluated in $Y\in\mathfrak{g}$, i have (2). $(3)\implies (4)$ is obvious. But i can't prove that $(2)\implies (3)$. Can someone show me the calculation for $(2)\implies(3)$ please?

Any help is appreciated and sorry for the bad English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t\in\mathbb R$ and $X\in\mathfrak g$. Then\begin{align}\mathrm d\phi\left(\operatorname{Ad}\left(e^{tX}\right)Y\right)&=\operatorname{Ad}\left(\phi\left(e^{tX}\right)\right)\mathrm d\phi(Y)\text{ by (2)}\\&=\operatorname{Ad}\left(e^{t\mathrm d\phi(X)}\right)\mathrm d\phi(Y).\end{align}Now, differentiating with respect to $t$ at $t=0$ will give you $(3)$.

Comment: Can you show me how to derive the first term d\phi(Ad(e^(tX)Y) ? (i don't know how insert equation in a comment). It seems that I have to exchange the derivative with respect to t with the phi differential. It is possible because the phi differential is linear?  If yes, how to justify this exchange?

Comment: I used the fact that$$\phi\left(e^{tX}\right)=e^{\mathrm d\phi(tX)}=e^{t\mathrm d\phi(X)}.$$And, yes, the second equality is due to the linearity of $\mathrm d\phi$. The fist equality is a standard property of the exponential map.

Comment: I said that badly, i mean how to differentiating w.r.t. t at t=0 the term d\phi(Ad(e^(tX)Y) to obtain the first term of (3). Can you show me how please? I know that the derivative of Ad(exp(tX)Y wrt t at t=0 is ad(X)Y, but seems that I have to exchange the derivative with respect to t with the phi differential.

Comment: Since $\mathrm d\phi$ is linear,$$\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\right|_{t=0}\mathrm d\phi\left(\operatorname{Ad}\left(e^{tX}\right)Y\right)=\mathrm d\phi\left(\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\right|_{t=0}\operatorname{Ad}\left(e^{tX}\right)Y\right).$$And$$\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\right|_{t=0}\operatorname{Ad}\left(e^{tX}\right)Y=[X,Y].$$